# How to use PHP natsort to sort out mysql records

Tags: php, mysql, columnsorting, natural-sort

I have been trying to sort out my mysql records with mysql queries but seems like its just impossible to do it in the natural order. I have values such as a1, a2, a3 through a200 and then b1 and so on but when sorting them out in mysql I get results such as a1, a10, a100 and any kind of undesired results so I wonder if php natsort is a better bet.

My table looks like this:

```
NAME         POSITION
a1             45
a2             67
a3             89
```

and so on, the point is to update the value in position according to the natural order of the value in NAME so a1 should be position 1, a2 should be 2 and so on. This is my PHP so far:

```
$values = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM table ORDER BY position ASC");
$sortit = natsort($values);

foreach($sortit as $pos=>$nam) {
 $mysqli->query("UPDATE table SET position=$pos WHERE name=$nam");
}
```

but I dont know where to go from here. Could you please put me in the right direction?

Comment: **Warning**: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterised **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. [Escaping is not enough](https://phpdelusions.net/top#escaping)

Comment: MariaDB-10.7 has [NATURAL_SORT_KEY](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/natural_sort_key/) for this purpose. Disclosure: I work for [MariaDB Foundation](https://mariadb.org)

Comment: `$mysqli->query()` returns a [mysqli_result](https://www.php.net/manual/class.mysqli-result.php), not the results of your query. You need to use one of the _fetch_ methods to get the results

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use `ORDER BY` in your query, since you're going to reorder it in PHP.

You need to get an array of all the names. `$mysqli->query()` returns a result object, not an array of the values.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM table");
$values = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $values[] = $row['name'];
}
natsort($values);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE table SET position = ? WHERE name = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("is", $pos, $nam);
foreach ($values as $pos => $nam) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

`natsort()` doesn't return the sorted array, it sorts the array in place.

Comment: sorry but I get an error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in line 17 (where $stmt is declared)

Comment: I don't see how that could be. I'm using the same `$mysqli` variable that you used in `$mysqli->query()`. How could it become a non-object between those two lines?

Comment: I dont know but I tweaked the code a little bit and I finally made it work Please see my answer. Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, thanks to Barmar for putting me in the right direction. This might not be the most elegant solution but it works just fine:

```
$result = $connect->query("SELECT name FROM table");
$values = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $values[] = $row['image'];
}

$sorted = $values;
natsort($sorted);
$i = 0;
foreach($sorted as $pos=>$nam) {
 $num = $i++;
 $sql = "UPDATE table SET position = '$num' WHERE name = '$nam'";
 mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
}
```